# I need to print the excel data from two columns in sequeal fromat. first column has single vaue and another column many values

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I wanted to read the data form the excel sheet which has first column has single value and another column many values like junk values need print first column value with second column value in sequential format. I couldn't figure it out how. I am using #java #apache-poi #selenium

The excel data is image:
[excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fgge.png)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Step 1: Open the excel workbook
        XSSFWorkbook wbook= new XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Selenium\\Data\\Mydata.xlsx");
        // Step 2: Go to the Sheet
                XSSFSheet sheet= wbook.getSheet("Reg Types");

                // Step a) Get the number of the rows of the sheet
                int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                System.out.println("The row countof the regtype: "+rowCount);
                // Step b) Get the number of the columns of the sheet
                int colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
                System.out.println("The column countof the regtype: "+colCount);

                    for (int i=1;i<=rowCount; i++)
                    {
                        // Step 3a: Go to the regtypecolumn
                        XSSFCell  regType= sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
                        // Step 3b: Save the value of the  regtype
                        String regTypeValue = regType.getStringCellValue();
                        //4 Print regtype and create query
                         System.out.println(regTypeValue);

                        // Step 5: Go to the optioncolumn junk values
                        XSSFCell  option= sheet.getRow(i).getCell(15);
                        // Step 5a: Save the value of the  option 
                        String optionValue = option.getStringCellValue();
                        String trimOptionValue=optionValue.replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll(",", " ");
                        //4 Print option and create query
                        System.out.println(trimOptionValue);

                    // Step 6: Close the workbook
                    wbook.close();              
    }
}
}


[Current output is][1]


[Expected output][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjS6y.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQrF.png
```

Current output

001
AFD PB_P PB_DL EGS_D1 EGS_D2 PC01 PC02 PC04M WREC

10A
AFD PB_P PB_DL EGS_D1 EGS_D2 PC01 PC02 PC03 PC04 PC01M PC02M

Expected output

001 AFD

001 PB_P

001 PB_DL

001  EGS_D1

001 EGS_D2

10A AFD

10A PB_P

10A PB_DL

10A EGS_D1

10A  EGS_D2

Comment: On each row, grab the value of the first cell, then as you iterate over the rest of the cells, print the first cell + that cell + newline?

Comment: After `String optionValue = option.getStringCellValue();` in your code `optionValue` is a string which you can split at the commas. `String[] options = optionValue.split(",");`. Now you have a string array containing the single options. Traverse that array for each row.